How to deal with '@' symbol in URLs within cshtml files
Does anyone know how I could use this in my cshtml file: <script src="https//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script> because of the '@' symbol its giving me this error: The name 'tensorflow' does not exist in the current contextCS0103.
I tried using @@ and the html encoded version of the @ symbol but the webpage wants the single '@' symbol evident by the error: Invalid URL. The URL structure is /npm/package@version/file.js

this is the url im trying to use:  

You just needed to format the HTML as code: see How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?

If this is a literal copy/paste (it should be in a question) then https://https// might be the problem. @@ sounds correct.

The link has now been changed in the question, but the same issue resides. When using @@ I get the error: Invalid URL. The URL structure is /npm/package@version/file.js

Both @@ and &#64; will output a single @ symbol. If it's not working for you, something you're not showing us is happening.

The solution is to wrap it with @()

Use @@ to escape single @ character.
Should look like <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@@tensorflow/tfjs"></…>.

Please search for duplicates before answering such questions.

I have tried using @@ and the html encoded version of the @ symbol but the webpage throws the error: The URL structure is /npm/package@version/file.js So i guess it has to use only one @ symbol
